# modify list until reach worst case time complexity

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with the worst possible input for my function (quick sort), what possible methods can I use to manipulate the list `x` in order to see the worst order x can be in to get the greatest number of steps.

```
def quick_sort_lst(lst):
    length = len(lst)
    if length <= 1:
        return lst
    else:
        pivot = lst.pop()  # remove last element to make it our pivot
    items_bigger = []
    items_smaller = []
    for element in lst:
        if element > pivot:
            items_bigger.append(element)
        else:
            items_smaller.append(element)
    return quick_sort_lst(items_smaller) + [pivot] + quick_sort_lst(items_bigger)


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
print(quick_sort_lst(x))
```

Comment: Ironically, the worst input is the already sorted list (both increasing and decreasing order) if you choose the greatest/least element as the pivot.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara are you saying the example `x` is already the worst case for a 12 element list?

Comment: Yes, print `items_bigger` and `items_smaller` before calling the quick sort and you should see it too.